# Enable Answer @replies to operate like Comment @replies

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, notifications

When a user posts an answer to a question and uses "@user" the user to whom they refer doesn't get a Notification, unlike [comment @replies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) which does alert the user about the post.

It would seem that if the answerer makes a point of writing @user in his answer (possibly referring to another answer or comment) that they intended to notify that person, otherwise they could have wrote the user's name without the at symbol.

Comment: Please....Don’t implement this feature...I would get so much unwanted spam

Comment: @Ramhound - The request has been decided upon. Why do you think people would write about "the user @Ramhound" rather than refer to you as "the user Ramhound". When you were born did your parents decide: "Let's name him @Gary."?

Comment: Being referred to in an answer and being notified of that fact will make my inbox go crazy.  Personal problem I suppose

Comment: Since you voted to close, you can approve the vote and bindingly mark this as a dupe.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Thanks, it didn't reload and I was working on your last comment elsewhere, so I was off doing something else; it wasn't until I returned to your ping that the dialog was visible.

Answer (score 7):

Answers are not for communicating something to a specific person; they are written for the general Internet audience, including of course the user who asked the question (and who gets notified of every answer).

If someone is trying to notify a user in an answer, well that's just their misguided intention.

Often though, this is not even intended as such; @ is used to indicate "username", the author being at or near the top phase of [Sigil Cycle](https://xkcd.com/1306/) ("we need these symbols to clarify what types of things we're referring to!")